# how to make condition for slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Iam beginner to JQuery mobile and i need some help to do this below calculation

i have this flip swatch

```
<form method="post" action="#" > 

 <label for="flip_1">option1 :</label>
<select name="flip_1" id="flip_1" data-role="slider" onchange="OnChange(this)">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select> 

 <label for="flip_2">option2 :</label>    
<select name="flip_2" id="flip_2" data-role="slider" onchange="OnChange(this)">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
    </select> 
</form>
  <div align="center">  <p id="demo">Result</p> </div>
```

and this java

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function OnChange(node) {
     if ($("#flip_1").val() == "on") {
            sum=sum+1;
            alert('flip_1_on');
    } else if ($("#flip_1").val() == "off") {
            sum=sum-1;
            alert('flip_1_off');
    }
    if ($("#flip_2").val() == "on") {
            sum=sum+1;
    } else if ($("#flip_2").val() == "off") {
            sum=sum-1;
    }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
    }
</script>
```

all i need is when i slide the flip_1 the result will be sum+1 and when i slide flip_1 again to be off the result will subtract by one result=sum-1;

and the same for flip_2

Comment: FYI the `language` attribute was deprecated ten years ago ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the change event in the pagecreate event of the jQM page

Given this markup (note i assigned the class myFilp to both switches and removed you inline script):

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <label for="flip_1">option1 :</label>
            <select name="flip_1" id="flip_1" class="myFlip" data-role="slider">
                <option value="off">Off</option>
                <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
            <label for="flip_2">option2 :</label>
            <select name="flip_2" id="flip_2" class="myFlip" data-role="slider">
                <option value="off">Off</option>
                <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <div align="center">
            <p id="demo">Result</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".myFlip").on("change", function () {
        var newval = $(this).val();
        if (newval == "on") {
            sum++;
        } else {
            sum--;
        }
        $("#demo").text("Result = " + sum);
    });
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9huyLdcd/2/)**

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and this amazing code but there on more thing  please to do 
what if i want on of this two slider to give a differnet value form the other  in other words i want flip one value to be +or-1 and the another flip swatch +or-3
how can i do  it ?

Comment: @AliGaaly, use a data-attribute on each flip to define how much to add/subtract on change (e.g. data-val="3"). Then in the change handler, get that value for the flipswitch which is changing using the .jqmData() method (e.g. $(this).jqmData("val")). Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9huyLdcd/3/

Comment: Thanks ezanker for all your help

Comment: @AliGaaly, you are welcome. If this solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer so future searchers know the problem was resolved.